# How to get Account address for person Account when queried from Contact

Tags: apex, person-accounts

In Account we have two standard address field 1. MailingAddress 2. PersonMailingAddress

Now for person account we are using general address feild i.e. Mailingaddresss, not PersonMailingAddress.

We know that person accounts are stored in both Account and Contact, so I want to query address field of person account from Contact.
Like this:

```
List<contact> con = [select Mailingaddress from Contact where isPersonAccount= true];
```

I investigated this issue and came to know that when Contact address field will store PersonMailingAddress for person Account. Since I am using Account's mailingaddress, so I'm not able to get address from Contact.

Thanks

Comment: If you query PersonMailingAddress (or MailingAddress) from Account where isPersonAccount=true you should get what you're looking for since one is mapped to the other.

Comment: No mailing address of account field is not mapped to any contact address